# Is it possible to use CREATE2 to replace a contract deployed with CREATE (self-destruct + same wallet to deploy)?

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment

the wallet A deploy a contract using CREATE(wallet,nonce) to the X address.

the contract at X can be self-destruct.

Is it possible for the same wallet A to deploy to the X address a new contract using CREATE2(wallet,salt,bytecode) ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: interesting question, though I wouldn't rely on this feature because they want to delete it in the future: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4758

Comment: a brief look at the sources tells that it is possible to recreate selfdestructed state object , well, at least there is no check for history of what happened in the past with this address

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you actually can.

I put this code in remix:

```
contract target{
    uint public myUint;

    constructor() {
        myUint = 1;
    }

    function destroy() external {
        selfdestruct(payable(address(0)));
    }
}


contract Example {

    function deploy(uint _salt) public returns(address newContract) {

        bytes memory bytecode = type(target).creationCode;
        assembly {
            newContract := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), _salt)
        }
    }
}
```

And I can deploy a target contract with the deploy() function (contract is at address 0x733C8B6...). I can call the myUint to check that it's = 1. Then I can call destroy() of the target contract and check that myUint = 0 since the contract was destroyed.
From there, I can call the deploy() function again and the newly created contract will also be at address 0x733C8B6!.

Try it yourself.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Read: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014. The formula for contract address with CREATE2 is prefixed with 0xff on purpose to avoid collisions with CREATE. The formula for address with CREATE is derived from RLP encoding of address and nonce and the first byte in RLP encoding signifies length, which is at most 52 bytes for address + nonce. However, 0xff implies petabytes of data, which is clearly impossible.